# Symfony2 - Creating a form need to pass in logged in user

Tags: forms, symfony, author

I have a reply form setup for replies to posts.

I want to setup the author to be the user currently logged in. Right now it's just a drop down menu of previous authors that's already posted, which isn't what I want.

How do I set it up to use the current logged in username as an author instead having a list of authors already saved to the database?

Is there a global command to access the currently logged in user to pass in to the `->add('author)` line in the form?

ReplyType form

```
class ReplyType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('author')
        ->add('body')
        ->add('post', 'submit');
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Reply'
    ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'acme_demobundle_reply';
}
}
```

**Reply entity**

```
/**
 * @var Author
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="replies")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $author;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the logged in user is the author, how about removing the field and setting the author to the currently logged in user inside the controller? The user should not actually select the author (ie: see Stackoverflow.com reply or comment forms).

```
// ...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function postReplyAction(Request $request)
{
    $reply = new Reply();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ReplyType(), $reply);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // perform your logic and before savig the reply to the database
        $reply->setAuthor($this->getUser());
        // save your reply

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('reply_success'));
    }

    // ...
}
```

And your form type becomes:

```
class ReplyType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('body')
            ->add('post', 'submit');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Reply'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_demobundle_reply';
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this brillant advice, question. I have my Reply entity setup as a many to one to an Author entity. Based on you solution how should I handle these 2 entities? I get a this value should not be blank when I remove  ->add('author') from my form. See above for Reply entity.

Comment: I removed the relationship with Reply and Author and have author as a string value in Reply. Now when I attempt to save a reply I get the following: `ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/SymChatter/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 120`

Comment: got it, used the `public function __toString()` fixed the error and now uses the `$this->getUser()` as the author. Thanks for the great help and explanation, tapeworm!